# SQL match beginning of all keywords

Tags: php, mysql, sql, jquery-ui

I will set up a scenario to best describe what I am trying to accomplish.

There is an autocomplete field. The autocomplete is for TV shows. The user inputs "The Wal" hoping to find "The Walking Dead".

The database:

```
CREATE TABLE `shows` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

CREATE TABLE `tags` (
  `tag` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `sid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  KEY `sid` (`sid`),
  KEY `alphabetizer` (`tag`),
  CONSTRAINT `tags_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`sid`) REFERENCES `shows` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Where `shows` is the table for all of the TV shows and `tags` is the table for all of the tags tied to each TV show.

Each word in each show title is inserted as its own lowercase tag in the `tags` table.

In the `shows` table:

- (id: 1) (name: The Walking Dead)
- (id: 2) (name: The Wandering Penguin)

In the `tags` table:

- (sid: 1) (tag: the)
- (sid: 1) (tag: walking)
- (sid: 1) (tag: dead)
- (sid: 2) (tag: the)
- (sid: 2) (tag: wandering)
- (sid: 2) (tag: penguin)

**Goal:** User inputs, "The Wal", user gets: "The Walking Dead". The query should return all results that meet the criteria, not just one. So if "The Walking Alive" were also a show with the corresponding tags, it should appear as well.

**My issue:** User inputs, "The Wal", user gets both shows. This is due to the OR clauses for the LIKE statement. I don't know how to fix this after trying for 2 days.

My current query:

```
SELECT name
    FROM shows s
    JOIN tags t ON s.id = t.sid
    WHERE t.tag LIKE "The%" OR t.tag LIKE "Wal%"
```

Comment: use `AND` clause instead of `OR` clause

Comment: @웃웃웃웃웃 This will not work. The field cannot be two values at the same time.

Comment: But in your table schema you shown it's like that

Comment: Added mysql tag because syntax is clearly MySQL.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you, I thought I had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to use `and` instead of `or`.  However, you need to use aggregation to get what you want:

```
SELECT name
FROM shows s JOIN
     tags t
     ON s.id = t.sid
WHERE t.tag LIKE 'The%' OR t.tag LIKE 'Wal%'
GROUP BY name
HAVING sum(t.tag LIKE 'The%') > 0 AND
       sum(t.tag LIKE 'Wal%') > 0;
```

However, I don't think that solves your problem, because you don't know that all keywords will match.  Instead, order by the number of keywords that do match and choose the best matching one:

```
SELECT name
FROM shows s JOIN
     tags t
     ON s.id = t.sid
WHERE t.tag LIKE 'The%' or t.tag LIKE 'Wal%'
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY (MAX(t.tag LIKE 'The%') +
          MAX(t.tag LIKE 'Wal%')
         ) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Hello, the second query returns nothing for me?

Comment: @GrayAdams . . . I made a bunch of edits to get the answer right.  Look at the current versions.

Comment: If there were another show named "The Walking Alive", then it would not appear with the second query as it should due to the limiter. Removing the limiter, though, may return far too many results and results that are not all relevant or that do not all match. The autocomplete would ideally return not just one show.

Comment: @GrayAdams . . . The easiest thing is to return some number from the second query, whatever your preferred limit is.

Comment: I am not following why the first query would not be ideal, as it seems to be returning the results I desire. Do you care to elaborate?

Comment: @GrayAdams . . . The first query requires that all the keywords be in the returned results.  The second orders the results by the ones with the most keywords first.  It is really up to you which is better.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to run this query is to add an `EXISTS` statement for each tag. This query can take advantage of a composite index on `tag(sid,tag)`

```
SELECT name
FROM shows s 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM tags t
    WHERE t.sid = s.id
    AND tag LIKE 'The%'
) AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM tags t
    WHERE t.sid = s.id
    AND tag LIKE 'Wal%'
)
```

Comment: This solution works as well. Performance wise, for the shows table I have with over 45,000 rows, it seems to be almost identical to Gordon's. Taking only 64ms remotely.

Comment: @GrayAdams did you add the composite index on `tag(sid,tag)`? although I suppose you can't get much faster than 64ms.

Comment: I hadn't. After doing so, it looks to have increased the performance, making this one a few milliseconds faster.

Comment: Would it make sense that the query takes some time the first time and less time the second? Noticeably so, as well. The autocomplete takes a solid second now. EDIT: While Gordon's solution takes less time when compared.

Comment: @GrayAdams the second query might take less time if it's been cached by mysql

Comment: I would like to agree, but when trying out Gordon's on new searches, it certainly pulls them up faster. Yours pulls them up noticeably slower, but then caches them and makes it quick the second time. I think Gordon's may actually be the best performing one. Though yours is prettier.

Comment: @GrayAdams i'm guessing the performance of the 2 approaches will depend on the uniqueness of your tags table. If you only have a few tags that have the same beginning, `join/group by` might be faster because the # of duplicate shows returned by the join would be low, if on the other hand you have many keywords with the same beginning `exists` might be faster

Answer (score 0):

**I don't think your approach is sound.** But here is an explanation of what is happening.

When you join `shows` to `tags` you get one record back for every word that's been matched so far.

Per your example, with

```
1. The Walking Dead
2. The Wandering Penguin
```

And this query

```
SELECT *
FROM shows s
JOIN tags t ON s.id = t.sid
WHERE t.tag LIKE "the%" OR t.tag LIKE "wa%" /* note lower-case query */
```

You'll get results

```
ID  NAME                  TAG
 1  The Walking Dead      the
 1  The Walking Dead      walking
 2  The Wandering Penguin the
 2  The Wandering Penguin wandering
```

If you had three words in your query that matched, you'd see different results

> Query: The Wa Dead

```
SELECT *
FROM shows s
JOIN tags t ON s.id = t.sid
WHERE t.tag LIKE "the%" OR t.tag LIKE "wa%" OR t.tag LIKE "dead"
```

would give

```
ID  NAME                  TAG
 1  The Walking Dead      the
 1  The Walking Dead      walking
 1  The Walking Dead      dead
 2  The Wandering Penguin the
 2  The Wandering Penguin wandering
```

You can eliminate the duplicates by using `GROUP BY` and score the results by number of words matched using `COUNT(*)`

```
SELECT s.name, COUNT(*)
FROM shows s
JOIN tags t ON s.id = t.sid
WHERE t.tag LIKE "the%" OR t.tag LIKE "wa%" OR t.tag LIKE "dead"
GROUP BY NAME
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

gives

```
 NAME                COUNT(*)
 The Walking Dead      3
 The Wandering Penguin 2
```

### What you should do

I think this indexing approach is probably not going to work well in the long term. Modern databases have built-in functions for this. [Here is a link to MySQL's full-text index feature](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html). This is a case where using the DB's native functionality will probably save you a major headache down the road, when your `tags` table reaches millions of rows and the JOIN of `shows` to `tags` becomes unmanageable.

Comment: I was wanting to use Fulltext, but due to being on shared hosting, I cannot upgrade to 5.6 so that I may use it on my InnoDB database. I need InnoDB for foreign keys. Unfortunately, the final query returns all shows that match ANY of the keywords, which was the initial problem. I understand that there are native functions in MyISAM databases for this, which likely means it is an effective way to manage the database if the native functions don't already exist (InnoDB).

Comment: @GrayAdams If you want to only match all the keywords, you can use HAVING COUNT(*) = num_keywords

Comment: Or else just punt on it and do WHERE show.NAME LIKE 'whatever the user typed%'

Comment: Also, if you wanted you could probably create a separate table that just has ID, NAME and is a copy of `shows` and is a MyISAM table. This should hold you over until you can update to > 5.6, while letting you index properly. I think that will probably be easier to manage than this tag table. You can use a trigger to copy the data from `shows` to `shows_index` (or whatever you call it). You could even add other fields to the index, so that your search auto-completes on more than just the title.

Answer (score 0):

I think the accepted answer is overcomplicated. Just add an input parameter "tags_count" and use it:

```
SELECT sid
  FROM tags t 
  WHERE t.tag LIKE "The%" OR t.tag LIKE "Wal%"
  GROUP BY sid
  HAVING count(distinct tag) = 2;
```

So we query only shows which contain all specified Tags

Comment: After running your query, it seems to pull up all tags that contain either "the%" or "wal%" still..

Comment: @GrayAdams I've tested in on "The Walking Dead" and "The Walking Alive" (count = 3) and have got expected results. Give please your test data.

Comment: because you're matching on wildcards using having count distinct can not guarantee that both tags are included in the count. if a show is associated with `The` and `There` but no `Wal%` tag, this query would return that show even though it shouldn't.

Comment: @FuzzyTree in your example count distinct Tag returns 1: `The` and `There` like the same tag `The`.

Comment: @VladimirChervanev I have tested it with over 45,000 rows, and it returns the same results my own query does.

Comment: @GrayAdams If you gave an example (tags and request) I'd be happy to test it, but I found another problem. 
Based on FuzzyTree comment I see another problem, for instance: A show "There Xхх they" vs request "The Yyy" will found two distinct tags although only one keyword works. Others answers might fall into similar trap e.g. "The There They" show versus "The"  request scores 3 hits and wins "The Walking Dead" (1 hit).